# Compile FreeReport in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi-7

When I compile FreeRep7.dpk project I have error message IBEXPRESS missing. I changed it to IBXPRESS.
Now I have an errors:

```
[Error] fr_intrp.pas(674): Incompatible types: 'WideChar' and 'Char'
[Fatal Error] Required package 'RXCTL6' not found
```

I Found http://sourceforge.net/projects/rxlib/ components, but this propably is not rxctl6 package ?

Comment: Have you contacted FR support?

Comment: I have found older version (2.34 ?) and it passed the compilation process.